# Ошибка IndexError: pop index out of range

Tags: python, list

Помогите пожалуйста, не могу понять в чём проблема. При запуске кода выводит ошибку IndexError: pop index out of range

```
from config import base
import random

test_base = random.choice(base)
test_base2 = random.choice(base)
print(f'{test_base} против {test_base2}') 
user_answer = input('Кто сильнее: ')
index1 = base.index(test_base)
index2 = base.index(test_base2)

while len(base) > 0:
```

> В сообщение об ошибке написано что проблема в строках base.pop(index1) и base.pop(index2)

```
    if user_answer == test_base2:
        base.pop(index1)
        

    elif user_answer == test_base:
        base.pop(index2)

    else:
        print('Не корректный ввод. Повторите попытку')
```

Comment: А что вам мешает самому проверить то значение, которое имеют ваши индексы при попытке выполнить указанные операции?

Comment: В переменой base находиться 58 элементов и суть в том что программа выводит пользователю 2 рандомных персонажей и после выбора пользователя удаляет вариант который остался. И ещё если что в переменой base находятся элементы типа str.

Comment: Я же спрашивал, не сколько там элементов. А спрашивал, что именно находится в индексах. И какие индексы у вашей "переменной base".

Comment: В индексах находятся строки. Я новичок и не совсем понял ваш вопрос 'какие индексы у вашей переменой base', если вы имели сколько индексов то их 58.

Comment: индексов 58, а какие числа содержатся в index1 и index2? Именно об этом самый первый комментарий

Comment: @KeyShark Если вы настолько новичок, то вам не с config разбираться сейчас надо, а учить основы Python. Иначе на каждый ваш вопрос вам будут отвечать, а у вас к ним будет возникать еще десяток вопросов. И так эта лавина будет только нарастать.  А вот тогда, когда будете понимать хотя-бы, что такое "индекс" -  вот тогда и можно НАЧИНАТЬ заниматься  чем нибудь посложнее, чем примеры из учебника.